# Redirecting output of info command

Tags: bash, info

While redirecting `info bash > file.info` on Ubuntu, I get a `file.info` file with just the error:

```
info: No menu item 'bash' in node '(dir)Top'
```

I tried to look at the location of the info page by using `info bash -w` which shows

```
*manpages*
```

I also could not find bash info page under `/usr/share/info`
but I did find it under `/usr/share/man/man1`.

However, I tried `info find > file.info` (find command had an info page under /usr/share/info)
which was successful.

Also `info bash` works fine.

My system - `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` with the kernel `5.11.0-25-generic`

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu, the bash manual is not installed by default, or only in the `man` format (and `info` falls back to displaying the man page when the `info` manual is not available) which is hardly usable for a manual of this size.

You need to install the `bash-doc` package first.

```
apt install bash-doc
```

(as `root`).

Same goes for most manuals in `info` format. For instance, you'd need to install `zsh-doc`, `gdb-doc`, `glibc-doc`, `gcc-doc`, `gawk-doc` to get manuals of those large software in more useful formats.

More generally, the software packages come with minimal documentation in `man` format, a few documents in `/usr/share/doc/<package-name>`, but larger documentation in other format (can be `info`, `html`...), when available are supplied in a `<package-name>-doc` package. That makes sense as users don't necessarily need the documentation, especially when software are installed as a dependency of another package and the users will never get to use them directly.

For some software libraries, the API documentation (generally in `man` format) is often supplied in the `<libpackage-name>-dev` package (again users are unlikely to need that information unless they're going to develop software for it), though again a `-doc` package can complete it with richer format/content.

Comment: is  `<package>-doc` for info/other richer docs required only for debian and its derivatives or also for other distros like arch, redhat, etc?